# Creating a welcome email via a program

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am trying to create a welcome email for my company. While I have the text bedded down, it does not  display correctly in all email clients. One way to do this is to use a `TextBox` or paste the text in a shape in Word. The borders remaining constant, the text remains within those borders and looks better. Given that I have about 1000 such welcome emails (each with name and login credentials), is there any other way to create these emails on the fly?

If so, what would I use to create via a program? HTML, PHP?

Comment: Do it in HTML. If you don't/can't handwrite it, use whatever tool you know best to generate it

Comment: [Litmus is a good tool for seeing what your HTML email looks like in various clients](http://litmus.com/email-testing) - If it's a one off, you can use the 7day trial. Also there's probably other free tools out there too.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all email clients will render html (with css)?

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used formatting the email as HTML and then writing the HTML to format the text as needed.

You could even use String.Format to insert the data where needed (borrowing the html from Silas because I didn't feel like making my own)

```
email.Body = String.Format("<html><body><h1>Welcome {0}</h1><div>{1}</div></body></html>", <user name>, <body of email>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create and HTML template and insert the text from the textbox inside the HTML template string.

Something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome #person#</h1>
        <div>#bodytext#</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then just replace "#person#" and "#bodytext#" before you ship it out.
That would even allow your collegues to edit the template if you allowed them to.

Comment: After I have the html in the desired format, I paste it into the compose window of the email client and hit send? Is it safe to assume that all email clients will render html correctly?